# SQL Server 2012 Change Data Capture Error 14234

Tags: sql-server, cdc, change-data-capture

I am having problems setting up change data capture on a SQL Server 2012 instance. Whenever I attempt to enable CDC on a table I get the following error:

> Msg 22832, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_cdc_enable_table_internal,
>   Line 623
>   Could not update the metadata that indicates table
>   [dbo].[TableName] is enabled for Change Data Capture.
>   The failure
>   occurred when executing the command '[sys].[sp_cdc_add_job] @job_type
>   = N'capture''.
>   The error returned was 22836: 'Could not update the metadata for database [database name] to indicate that a Change Data Capture
>   job has been added. The failure occurred when executing the command
>   'sp_add_jobstep_internal'.
>   The error returned was 14234: 'The
>   specified '@server' is invalid (valid values are returned by
>   sp_helpserver).'. Use the action and error to determine the cause of
>   the failure and resubmit the request.'. Use the action and error to
>   determine the cause of the failure and resubmit the request.

The name of the server has not changed, I tried the `sp_dropserver`  / `sp_addserver` solution and receive the following error:

> Msg 15015, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dropserver, Line 42
>   The server 'ServerName' does not exist. Use sp_helpserver to show
>   available servers.
>
> Msg 15028, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addserver, Line 74
>   The server 'ServerName' already exists.

As I've stated, I'm trying to set up CDC and not replication. The version of SQL Server is: 11.0.5058.0 (SQL Server 2012 SP2)

I've looked at [Error while enabling CDC on table level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969742/error-while-enabling-cdc-on-table-level) and tried that solution.

I've also tried:

```
exec sys.sp_cdc_add_job @job_type = N'capture'
```

I receive the following error:

> Msg 22836, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_cdc_add_job_internal, Line 282
>   Could not update the metadata for database [DatabaseName] to indicate
>   that a Change Data Capture job has been added. The failure occurred
>   when executing the command 'sp_add_jobstep_internal'.
>   The error returned was 14234: 'The specified '@server' is invalid (valid values are returned by sp_helpserver).'. Use the action and error to
>   determine the cause of the failure and resubmit the request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ensure the [SQL Server Agent is running](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190695.aspx).

Comment: SQL Agent is up and running

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 10):

As listed here, check the names match

```
SELECT srvname AS OldName FROM master.dbo.sysservers
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS NewName
```

If not, fix with:

```
sp_dropserver '<oldname>';  
GO  
sp_addserver '<newname>', local;  
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused due to mismatch in value between SERVERPROPERTY(‘ServerName’)) and master.dbo.sysservers

Answer (score 1):

Check these SQLs:

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysservers
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')
```

If your `SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')` is not any of the `sysservers`, then the fix is to change your computer name to match one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the server fixes the issue:

```
DECLARE @ServerName NVARCHAR(128) = CONVERT(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('servername'));
EXEC sp_addserver @ServerName, 'local';
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, where I have restored a bak file which I got from another windows machine,which retained windows user account with the old PC name. I had delete the backup, create an empty data base and restore into that. This solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Query the following database table:

```
select * from msdb.dbo.cdc_jobs;
```

Clean all entries in that instance:

```
delete from msdb.dbo.cdc_jobs where database_id='<database_id>';
```